# os.getenv("username") not returning environment variable instead my name

Tags: python, operating-system, environment-variables

So I was using a API and had to give my account username and password. I kept getting a authentication error, and was very confused.

After a lot of time it turns out that os.getenv("username") wasn't returning the environment vairable but instead my name. I  checked the source code but in truth could not make sense of it lol. If anyone knows why this was the case and could tell me that would be awesome.

I know the module has something to do with the operating system but this was on the .env documentation so I'm just surprised it didn't work as expected.

here is the code all though I doubt it will be that useful, fixed since last commit: https://github.com/shers003/firstRedditbot

Comment: Is this on Windows? It seems like `username` is a built-in environment variable: https://www.rapidee.com/en/environment-variables. Could you just use another name that's not overlapping the one Windows uses?

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have gained some knowledge. Yep I did change the variable name and it works just fine now.

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.rapidee.com/en/environment-variables), `username` is a built-in environment variable in Windows. The solution is to use a different name.